# How do I resolve a year/month/day date to a more specific date with time data in MongoDB?

Tags: .net, mongodb, datetime, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm working on converting my blog over to use `/year/month/day` type URLs. I've ran into a pretty bad problem with the concept though. I want to only have down to hour/minute resolution, but of course all of my entries are stored with a full time specific as possible(and I don't want to change that).

How exactly do I go about resolving a specific date to a less specific date with MongoDB? I'm using 10gen's official MongoDB mapper for .Net.

My data-model looks like:

```
public class BlogEntryData
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId ID;
    public string Title;
    public string Text;
    public DateTime Posted;
    public DateTime Edited;
    public List<string> Tags;
    [BsonDefaultValue(true)]
    public bool Publish;
}
```

and I get an entry for my blog using

```
var c=Config.GetDB().GetCollection<BlogEntryData>("entries");
BlogEntryData entry;
try
{
    entry=c.FindOneByIdAs<BlogEntryData>(new ObjectId(RouteParams["id"]));
}
catch
{
    throw new HttpException(404,"Blog entry not found");
}

if(entry==null)
{
    throw new HttpException(404,"Blog entry not found");
}
```

I'm know how to change it to use instead of ID something like a numerical search field or whatever, but I've never queried against dates.

Also, as an aside, would it be better to store the "URL date" denormalized as a string in my entry model? I'd only want to do this if indexes didn't work properly on dates or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your DateTimes can be represented in Mongo with the following syntax;

```
ISODate("2012-10-11T17:33:51.994Z")
```

Which is the canonical, sortable format. So it starts with year, then month, then day, then hour etc, so it's already least to most specific order. There's a couple of things you can do with this.

1. You can do string parsing over it, just using the first part of the string. But that's not too smart.
2. You can simply duplicate the year and month as separate fields, in *addition* to the ISODate(). The advantage here is that you can reference those fields directly and you can index them specifically.
3. Finally, you can search using a range, the shorthand for which can be used thus;

> db.so.find({Posted:{$gt: ISODate("2012-10-11"),
>   $lt:ISODate("2012-10-12")}})

I wouldn't recommend 1 at all, but 2 and 3 would work very well.

And incidentally, both those mechanisms would translate well into the C# driver. So by way of a more complete answer;

```
        var dayOfInterest = new DateTime(2012, 10, 11);
        var rangeOfInterest = dayOfInterest.AddDays(1);

// ...

         var entries = c.FindAs<BlogEntryData>(Query.And(
                                    Query.GT("Posted", dayOfInterest),
                                    Query.LT("Posted", rangeOfInterest)
                         ));
```

Comment: ISODates are stored ( http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dates ) as `the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch` not in string format. The indexing strategy of housing all the date parts separately would not be ultra performant, also it would increase your working set size and RAM needs for the index and storage needs and querying time and may make sharding much harder forcing global ops for data retrieval. It is better instead to just query via a standardised set of time as shown by the C# code.

Comment: Sorry, reading my reply again, I didn't mean to imply that dates are STORED as strings. In fact they are longs. But my recommendations for 2 & 3 still stand. You're right about RAM. But storing denormalised year and date is still a value approach. It all depends on your query pattern. I hope amongst those options you have a workable solution though. Kind regard

Comment: So long as it is cleared up :) Otherwise people will start thinking the first method is possible. Though in C# it may actually contain a `toString` function but I wouldn't know since I haven't done MongoDB with C#, but this is language dependant.

Comment: Indeed, point 2 is workable but those points need to be taken into consideration when doing it, it's as you said, all down to querying pattern.

Comment: Option 3 will work for me. I wouldn't gain anything by denormalizing it, as I never have a search-by-year or such function

Comment: In fact if you think about it, using the ISODate() ctor syntax (shell example) is accepting a string pattern, but it's unlikely you'd be doing that from a driver (as per code sample).

Answer (score 0):

Before I get started, let me make sure that I understood your question correctly.  You are currently storing dates in the Date/Time format, but would like to be able to use and query on the dates in a less finely grained way.  If this is what you were wondering, then I have some good news for you: all of this is quite simple in mongodDB.

First of all, you should read [the mongodb cookbook post on this topic](http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/date_range/) to learn how to query and index on dates inside of mongodb.

Secondly, once you have the date in c#, it is (I believe, I tried to confirm with some searches but am still not 100% sure) in the c# DateTime class.  This class has quite a few methods that can be used to view the date with different granularity.  For more info on the subject look at the [microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx)

Hopefully this answers your questions and gives you the tools you need to keep on enjoying mongodb