# Querying by date, regardless time part

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date, mongoose

I want to show my blog posts, paginated by creation date. I will have a page for 5 posts written in 2012-10-01, a page for 11 posts written in 2012-10-03 and no page at all for 2012-10-02 (no posts written)

Each post document is stored with a creation date which is a datetime value, here's a mongoose snippet:

```
var postSchema = new Schema({
    url: String,
    creationDate: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    contenuto: String,
});
```

so it will have something like 2012-10-01 18:45:03... know what I mean.

In my code, I will create a

```
var searchDate = new Date(yy,mm,dd);
```

**How can I use that for querying the posts collection, without considering the "time part" of creationDate?**

I'm not sure this would always work:

```
Post.find({ creationDate:dataRicerca })
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per this post;

[How do I resolve a year/month/day date to a more specific date with time data in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831025/how-do-i-resolve-a-year-month-day-date-to-a-more-specific-date-with-time-data-in/12849923#12849923)

you can store the data separately (as well as the full date) in your schema for easier searching. You could also do this;

```
Post.find({Posted:{$gt: Date("2012-10-01"), $lt:Date("2012-10-02")}})
```

(updated to use Date() rather than ISODate() for better compatibility)

Comment: I'll try the second option (composing each time the string for ISODate()) and let you know. Thank you.

Comment: well you can just use Date() don't forget.

Comment: NP. I have separate "year" "month" and "date" strings, so.

Comment: There's a ticket regarding partial date queries here (https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-465) and the advice was to store year and month separately. The user there has also tried RegEx queries over dates (as strings).

Comment: Shouldn't we use `new Date` instead of just `Date`?